# How to change ID of textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create multiple textboxes along with a checkbox and a button at runtime based upon the input coming during the runtime.

The user will have the option of deleting the textbox along with the checkbox and button by pressing the button.

This works fine.

If the user deletes one of the textboxes along with the checkbox by pressing the button, then all the remaining IDs should move one value up.

This part is not working fine.

```
for(i = 0; i <= k; i++) { 
    if (document.getElementById("cbox" + i).checked == true) { 
        var n = i.toString()   
        var textbox = document.createElement('input');
        textbox.type = 'text'; 
        textbox.id = "tbox" + i;
        textbox.value = document.getElementById("texts" + i).value;    

        document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(textbox);

        var cb = document.createElement('input');
        cb.type = 'checkbox';
        cb.checked = true;  
        cb.id = 'cbid' + i;
        document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(cb);    

        var btn = document.createElement('input');     
        btn.type = 'button';    
        btn.value = 'delete';   
        btn.name = 'delete';    
        btn.id = i.toString();  
        btn.onclick = function () {    
            var tbx = "tbox" + this.id;
            var cbx = "cbid" + this.id;
            var btndel = this.id;
            var x;                  

            (elem = document.getElementById(tbx)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            (elem = document.getElementById(cbx)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            (elem = document.getElementById(btndel)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);                

            for(x = btndel + 1; x <= 10; x++) { 
                document.getElementById('tbox' + x).id = "tbox" + (x - 1);
                document.getElementById("cbid" + x).id = "cbid" + (x - 1);
                document.getElementById(x).id = x - 1;
            }

            document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(btn);
        };
```

Comment: I'd advise against using IDs in this way, building the strings, assigning them, then re-assigning. There are much better ways to keep track of your elements.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with @torazaburo

but if I were to humor you
does `btndel` even have a numerical value? It looks like your convention for ID is `tbox1` or something like that, so how would you initiate a for loop with `i = tbox1`?

Comment: btndel is a numerical value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var totalElem = 20
        for (i = 0; i <= totalElem; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById("cbox" + i).checked == true) {
                var n = i.toString()
                var textbox = document.createElement('input');
                textbox.type = 'text';
                textbox.id = "tbox" + i;
                textbox.value = document.getElementById("texts").value;
                document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(textbox);
                var cb = document.createElement('input');
                cb.type = 'checkbox';
                cb.checked = true;
                cb.id = 'cbid' + i;
                document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(cb);
                var btn = document.createElement('input');
                btn.type = 'button';
                btn.value = 'delete';
                btn.name = 'delete';
                btn.id = i.toString();
                btn.onclick = function () {
                    var tbx = "tbox" + this.id;
                    var cbx = "cbid" + this.id;
                    var btndel = this.id;
                    var x = btndel;
                    (elem = document.getElementById(tbx)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                    (elem = document.getElementById(cbx)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                    (elem = document.getElementById(btndel)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                    for (x = parseInt(btndel) + 1; x <= totalElem; x++) {
                        document.getElementById('tbox' + x).id = "tbox" + (x - 1);
                        document.getElementById("cbid" + x).id = "cbid" + (x - 1);
                        document.getElementById(x).id = x - 1;
                    }
                    totalElem -= 1;

                };
                document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(btn);

            }
        }
```

Try this if it helps you

Comment: thanks for the kind help, using parseInt(btndel) worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it easily by jQuery.

```
//HTML:
<div id="generatedElements"><p></p></div>

//jQuery
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var NoElems =3;
        var Str ="";
        for(var i =0; i<NoElems; i++)
            Str = Str + "<input type='checkbox' id='check"+i+"'/><input type='text' id='text"+i+"'/><br/>";
        $("#generatedElements p").html(Str);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain global variable which will have the count of total TextBoxes along with its CheckBox.

```
var gCount = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("cbox" + i).checked == true) {
        var n = i.toString()
        var textbox = document.createElement('input');
        textbox.type = 'text';
        textbox.id = "tbox" + i;
        textbox.value = document.getElementById("texts" + i).value;
        document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(textbox);
        var cb = document.createElement('input');
        cb.type = 'checkbox';
        cb.checked = true;
        cb.id = 'cbid' + i;
        document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(cb);
        var btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.type = 'button';
        btn.value = 'delete';
        btn.name = 'delete';
        btn.id = i.toString();

        //increment count
        gCount++;
        btn.onclick = function() {
            var tbx = "tbox" + this.id;
            var cbx = "cbid" + this.id;
            var btndel = this.id;
            var x;
            (elem = document.getElementById(tbx)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            (elem = document.getElementById(cbx)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            (elem = document.getElementById(btndel)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            for (x = 0; x < gCount; x++) {
                document.getElementById('tbox' + x).id = "tbox" + x;
                document.getElementById("cbid" + x).id = "cbid" + x;
                document.getElementById(x).id = x;
            }
            document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(btn);
        };
```